# How to load filtered QueryTable to Excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Provided I have the data in following format in the DB:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
| Server | Client | Usage |
+--------+--------+-------+     
| London | Bob    | 10%   |
| London | Alice  | 20%   |
| Tokyo  | Charlie| 30%   |
| Tokyo  | Zeke   | 40%   |
+--------+--------+-------+
```

I would like to have a spreadsheet containing data for each `Server` but I don't know in advance which servers will be present and in what numbers. Via the *Data > Connection* I have created the CommonConnection would get all the data.

**Question**: Is there a way to display information for each server on a separate spreadsheet, using this single connection? Something like `SELECT * FROM %CommonConnection% WHERE Server='London'` (the `%%` syntax is speculative).

I'm writing a VBA script that will read servers, create spreadsheets for each and set up filters. Now it seems I'll have to have a connection for a list of servers, and then create a dedicated connection for each of servers. These connection will have to be deleted on reload since I don't know exact number of servers.

Comment: Is this a report for distribution as a static document, or can it be updated later?  You might be better off looking at using ADO and creating the sheets as you process the result set.

Comment: I'm looking into distributing the document (within intranet) that could update itself. Current (but limited) similar solution exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I havent found a native way of doing it, so everything is done via macro. This solution has multiple drawbacks one being you must have special extension for a macro-enabled workbook `.xlsm`.

```
Set cnt = New ADODB.connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

cnt.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security= ...."
rst.Open "SELECT ...", cnt

While Not rst.EOF
    server = rst.Fields(0).Value
    ' get other values as well
    Worksheets(server).Range("whatever").Value = Array(server, value1, value2, etc)
Wend
```